# Virtualenv and libpython

Tags: python-3.x

I'm running arch, and on a project I had set up previously I used virtualenv to set up a little python sandbox. At this point in time the default python version on my box was 3.2 It has since been upgraded to 3.3, but when I go into my (now old) virtualenv and try to run python I get the error:

```
python: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.2mu.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Is this something I can fix so that in the future if/when I upgrade my python I don't end up missing libraries that old virtualenv's need?

Comment: Have you tried Pipenv? https://github.com/kennethreitz/pipenv

Answer (score 1):

Virtualenvs directly depend on the python runtime they were created from so when you remove the runtime, the virtualenv stops working too.

The solution is to use [pipenv](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv) instead of the `virutalenv` package because it contains all of your project's dependencies in a file called **Pipfile** in the top-level folder. There is a pipenv package in Arch Linux [here](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/any/python-pipenv/). For a standalone python installation it can easily be installed using `pip3 install pipenv`.

Whenever Python is replaced (or in your case upgraded), you must remove the previous virtualenv using `pipenv --rm` in the directory the environment is located. But after upgrading Python, you must edit the Pipfile manually to delete the `python_version = "3.7"` (or whatever version it is) line from the file because this causes `pipenv shell` or the `python3` invocation inside it to fail after the old environment has been removed.

Note that in this method the virtualenv is still tied to the python version that you ran `pipenv shell` against. If you simultaneously install another python version, install the pipenv package for it and try to run `pipenv shell`, it will use the python runtime the virtualenv it was created with (the first python runtime).

I tested all this by building a Python 3.7 runtime on Cloud9 and got pipenv for it. Then I deleted that and built a Python 3.5 runtime in the same installation directory also with pipenv. Then I deleted that too and built Python 3.8 similarly. Finally I installed Python 3.7 alongside 3.8, both with pipenv.